# One page is redirected to home and I don't understand why

Tags: redirect

This URL https://www.royaumont.com/les-residences-de-creation-choregraphique/alice-lambert-lucie-palazot/ is the permalink of a page in my Wordpress. But it is redirected to the homepage https://www.royaumont.com.

I have disabled the WP Super Cache plugin, the Redirection plugin, cleared the Varnish cache, but it is still redirected.

There are no redirections in the htaccess file.

I don't understand where this redirection comes from !
It is also the same for some other similar URL :
https://www.royaumont.com/les-residences-de-creation-choregraphique/doria-belanger/
https://www.royaumont.com/les-residences-de-creation-choregraphique/leila-ka/

But it's OK for some others :
https://www.royaumont.com/les-residences-de-creation-choregraphique/sebastien-laurent/
https://www.royaumont.com/les-residences-de-creation-choregraphique/caroline-grosjean/

Comment: when did this start happening, are there calls to `wp_redirect` or `wp_safe_redirect` in your code?

Comment: view-source:https://www.royaumont.com/les-residences-de-creation-choregraphique/alice-lambert-lucie-palazot/ shows this isn't a 302 redirect from one of those functions, it's something taking over the page and using a meta tag to redirect. At this point I don't think it's possible to answer this with just what you've provided, you can proceed with a process of elimination, disabling plugins and searching your admin area for settings and config areas that might give clues. Disabling plugins should provide strong hints as to which plugin is responsible and why. This can't be diagnosed remotely

Comment: importantly, if this is something inside your theme then it will be impossible for people online to help you without making public a full copy of the code which would be a big security risk

Comment: Thank @Tom, searching for redirect in the theme was the good tip.

Comment: if you've found it write an answer below for other people with the same problem, I can upvote your comment but you get points for answer upvotes

Comment: In fact, this was caused by something very specific to my project. It won't help others.

Comment: it's still worth doing, if not because it gives clues to others, or makes it clear that it won't, but also because the site will keep suggesting this question to others trying to get you an answer, and people will turn up asking you if you found a solution because none is listed below